# Space of real sequences is separable

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

My task is to

> prove that the metric space $(\textbf{s},d_{\textbf{s}})$ is separable, where $\textbf{s}$ is the set of any real sequence with metric defined by
>
> $$d_{\textbf{s}}(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{i}} \frac{|x_{i} - y_{i}|}{1 + |x_{i} - y_{i}|}, \hspace{2mm} \forall x = \{x_{i}\}, y = \{y_{i}\} \in \textbf{s})$$

I know that I need to find a countable dense subset of $\textbf{s}$, and my instinct is to appeal to $\mathbb{Q}$ in some way, but I'm kind of floundering here. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Show that it is complete and completely bounded.

Comment: Completeness has not been yet introduced in this course so I would suppose this proof would not utilize an argument of completeness.

Comment: Rough idea: Note that if $\pi_n x$ represent the truncation of $x$, that is, $\pi_n x = (x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n, 0,0,0,\cdots)$ then $d_s(\pi_n x, x) \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Then approximate this $\pi_n x$ by $(y_1, \cdots, y_n, 0,0,0, \cdots)$ so that $y_i \in \mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing my homework recently, which has the same question. I came up with the following rough proof, **which may have many mistakes**. Though it has been seven years since this question opened, I hope this may help someone.

First, we introduce a set $M$, which we want to prove is a dense subset of $S = \{ \{x_n\}, x_n \in \mathbb{R} \}$:
$$
M = \{ \{x_n\}, x_n \in \mathbb{Q}, \exists N \ge 1, \forall n \ge n + 1, x_n = 0 \}
$$
That is, $M$ is a set of sequence like $(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_N, 0, \cdots)$

Say we have a sequence $\textbf{x} \in S$, a simal number $\epsilon > 0$, then
$$
\exists N \ge 1 \text{ s.t. } \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \frac{|x_n|}{1 + |x_n|}
$$

> I believe this can be proved since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \frac{|x_n|}{1 + |x_n|} < 1$

Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$

$$
\exists y_1, y_2, \cdots, y_N \in \mathbb{Q} \text{ s.t. } \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{2^N} \frac{|x_n - y_n|}{1 + |x_n - y_n|} < \frac{\epsilon}{2}
$$

So we have $\textbf{y} = (y_1, \cdots, y_N, 0, \cdots) \in M$, then
$$
\begin{align}
d_S(\textbf{x}, \textbf{y}) & = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \frac{|x_n - y_n|}{1 + |x_n - y_n|} \\
& = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{2^n} \frac{|x_n - y_n|}{1 + |x_n - y_n|} + \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \frac{|x_n|}{1 + |x_n|} \\
& < \epsilon
\end{align} 
$$

Thus, $\textbf{y} \in M \cap B(\textbf{x}, \epsilon) \ne \emptyset$

Since $\epsilon$ can be any positive real number, $\textbf{x} \in \bar{M} \iff \bar{M} = S \iff M$ is a dense subset of $S$.

Then, we want to prove that $M$ is countable. Say we have a subset of $M$
$$
M_k = \{ \{x_n\}, x_n \in \mathbb{Q}, \forall n \ge k + 1, x_n = 0 \}
$$

It is obvious that we can have a map $\sigma: M_k \to \mathbb{Q}^k, \{x_n\} \mapsto (x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_k)$.

This means $M_k \sim \mathbb{Q}^k$.

We know $\mathbb{Q}^k$ is countable, then $M_k$ is also countable.

Thus, $M = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty M_k$ is also countable. So we can say $(S, d_S)$ is separable.